# PHPUnit mocking an object don't work

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, symfony-components

I'm new to mocking objects in PHPUnit and can't get it working. I am building an extension of the current `SensioGeneratorBundle` (for Symfony2). I use **PHPUnit 3.7** installed via `PEAR`. It is running on **PHP 5.3.5** (as PEAR is installed in that version).

My stripped classes are:

*ControllerGenerator.php*

```
class ControllerGenerator extends Generator
{
    // ...

    public function generate(BundleInterface $bundle, $controller, array $actions = array())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

*GenerateControllerCommand.php*

```
class GenerateControllerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    private $generator;

    /**
     * @see Command
     */
    public function configure()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // ...

        $generator = $this->generator;
        $generator->generate($bundle, $controller);

        // ...
    }

    protected function getGenerator()
    {
        if (null === $this->generator) {
            $this->generator = new ControllerGenerator($this->getContainer()->get('filesystem'), __DIR__.'/../Resources/skeleton/bundle');
        }

        return $this->generator;
    }

    public function setGenerator(ControllerGenerator $generator)
    {
        $this->generator = $generator;
    }
}
```

*GenerateControllerCommandTest.php*

```
class GenerateControllerCommandTest extends GenerateCommandTest
{
    public function testNonInteractiveCommand()
    {
        $bundle = 'FooBarBundle';
        $controller = 'PostController';

        $input = array(
            'command' => 'generate:controller',
            '--bundle' => $bundle,
            '--controller' => $controller,
        );

        $application = $this->getApplication();
        $commandTester = $this->getCommandTester($input);
        $generator = $this->getGenerator();

        $generator
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('generate')
            ->with($this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getBundle($bundle), $controller)
        ;

        $commandTester->execute($input, array('interactive' => false));
    }

    protected function getCommandTester($input = '')
    {
        return new CommandTester($this->getCommand($input));
    }

    protected function getCommand($input = '')
    {
        return $this->getApplication($input)->find('generate:controller');
    }

    protected function getApplication($input = '')
    {
        $application = new Application();

        $command = new GenerateControllerCommand();
        $command->setContainer($this->getContainer());
        $command->setHelperSet($this->getHelperSet($input));
        $command->setGenerator($this->getGenerator());

        $application->add($command);

        return $application;
    }

    protected function getGenerator()
    {
        // get a noop generator
        return $this
            ->getMockBuilder('Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\ControllerGenerator')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('generate'))
            ->getMock()
        ;
    }
}
```

When I run PHPUnit, I keep getting this error:

```
 $ phpunit Tests\Command\GenerateControllerCommandTest

     PHPUnit 3.7.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.

     Configuration read from E:\Wouter\web\wamp\www\wjsnip\vendor\sensio\generator-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\phpunit.xml.dist

     F

     Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 7.25Mb

     There was 1 failure:

     1) Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Tests\Command\GenerateControllerCommandTest::testNonInteractiveCommand
     Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:generate> when invoked 1 time(s).
     Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.

     E:\Wouter\web\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\phpunit:46

     FAILURES!
     Tests: 1, Assertions: 7, Failures: 1.
```

Why am I getting this error? I think I called the `generate` command in the `GenerateControllerCommand::execute` method? Am I doing something wrong, possible true? Or is this a bug in PHPunit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In short

You generate two differnt `$generator` objects. The call happens to one while the other `expect`s it.

---

### Longer

You change the behavior `protected function getGenerator()` but the original function expects that calling that function populates `$this->generator`.

Your test is not working as you and the function expects to always get the same generator and with your overwrite the function returns two different objects.

You set the expected call on one and the call happens to the object.

Just looking at:

```
    $generator = $this->getGenerator();

    $generator
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('generate')
        ->with($this->getContainer()->get('kernel')->getBundle($bundle), $controller)
    ;

    $commandTester->execute($input, array('interactive' => false));
}
```

The `$generator` variable is not put in any object scope anywhere and hence no calls can happen on it as every call to `$this->getGenerator()` produces a new object that is not stored anywhere.

So in

```
protected function getApplication() {
    //...
    $command->setGenerator($this->getGenerator());
    //...
}
```

you have a different object than you have in your test case.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I have solved it, the `getGenerator` and `setGenerator` methods of the test object work now the same as in the command object.